# Why don't we put GRUB config files on the ESP?

Tags: configuration, grub, boot-loader, refind

I have been reading through GRUB manuals, and one there is one choice with respect to GRUB that doesn't seem to make sense to me. Every tutorial that I have found chooses to install GRUB "tethered" to a specific OS installed on their drive. To be more specific, it seems that the preferred location for GRUB configuration files is on the `/boot` drive for the OS that "manages" GRUB.

One option here is to simply mount your ESP at `/boot`, although this seems ill-advised because it makes more sense to keep the kernel on the same partition as the root directory for each OS. Another option, and the option which I'm afraid I don't understand isn't the preferred method, is to simply put the GRUB files (grub.cfg, etc -- the files that are usually installed at `/boot/grub`) under `/esp/grub`. It still seems slightly janky that even then the primary config files (`/etc/default/grub`, etc.) are still tied to a specific operating system, instead of being globally managed (as what they are configuring is a global entity: the boot process for the entire computer.)

rEFInd seems to have a better thought-out process when it comes to the boot processes (it puts a global configuration file on `/esp` and puts OS-specific config files on each operating system's boot drive).

I don't entirely understand what the downsides to the above-mentioned strategy that rEFInd uses in contrast to the GRUB config strategy, nor do I understand what downsides there would be with having GRUB use a similar strategy (leveraging the `--efi-directory` and `--boot-directory` flags enables the user to *mostly* do what I mentioned above, but I have yet to see a single tutorial indicate that using these might lead to a cleaner config setup).

Are there major downsides to what I've outlined above, and why does GRUB continue to enforce the "one primary management OS for the configuration files" strategy? Does the old way continue to be used simply to provide some semblance of backwards compatibility?

Comment: "because it makes more sense to keep the kernel on the same partition as the root directory for each OS" Ubuntu notoriously does the opposite, it makes a tiny boot partition and puts kernel images there, which often leads to errors about the partition getting full and package upgrades erroring out

Comment: @muru Doesn't Ubuntu official Installer let you choose partition scheme?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 it does, and the default is a tiny `/boot`.

Comment: you use VFS path, which doesn't specify which file on which partition at all